How do I use FormKit inside a Vue based web component
See this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/little-breeze-lnlfzp

I've defined the two components as custom elements
Registered them both in main.ts
Created a Vue App with FormKit as plugin and added it to a random div defined in index.html
The two components work ok and communicate over the pure js main site.
When adding FormKit elements to the component I get warnings and errors and nothing is shown.

My questions:

How do I get the FormKit elements to work inside the custom element? I've added it to the first component and I get an error, even with using FormKitRoot. Maybe I'm using it wrong?
How do I prevent vite from including Vue in the web components and make them share the existing app instance?


Hi, questions on Stack Overflow need to ask one thing. Please edit your question to remove one of your two questions. Also, please add your code from the sandbox _directly into your post. Questions about code need to include that code as text in the question. See [mcve] for more information.
